# atomic store compilation problem on linux

Tags: c++, c++11, stdatomic

The code

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

static shared_ptr<multimap<string,int> > m1;
//static atomic<shared_ptr<multimap<string,int> > > m3;
int main()
{
     multimap<string,int> m2;
     m2.insert(make_pair("1",1));
     //m3.store(std::make_shared<multimap<string,int> >(m2),std::memory_order_relaxed);
     atomic_store(&m1, std::make_shared<multimap<string,int> >(m2));
}
```

works fine with gcc -dumpversion = 4.2.1 on mac, on Linux it is 4.8.5 it won't even compile, after changing it into commented out lines, syntax compilation failure goes away, but generates

```
/tmp/ccM6frcE.o: In function `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::multimap<std::string, int, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > > > >::store(std::shared_ptr<std::multimap<std::string, int, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > > >, std::memory_order)':
tt.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6atomicISt10shared_ptrISt8multimapISsiSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsiEEEEE5storeES9_St12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicISt10shared_ptrISt8multimapISsiSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsiEEEEE5storeES9_St12memory_order]+0x3a): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

is there any unresolved symbol/function problem?

compiling it like this on Linux

```
g++ --std=c++11 tt.cpp
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on linux x64: clang 8.0 and gcc 8.3 (with the commented out lines). That gcc version is ancient....

Comment: You probably need to link with `-latomic` if this non-lock-free operation didn't inline, and called a helper function.